# Stacking Columns Vertically in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, android-glide, airtable

I have a google sheet table that has 4 columns, Name (of project), Email (of user), Year 1 (revenues), Year 2 (revenues). I would like to convert it into 4 columns: Name, Email, Year, Revenue so that I can put that data into Airtable or similar.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z51XE.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvxPT.png)

I can't seem to find a way of doing it.

The purpose behind this is that my table actually has data for 15 years (instead of 2), and the app charting tool wouldn't let me chart a table that has years running as columns (it needs to be in rows)

Tried Arrayformulas, Flatten, Transpose.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=lambda(z,filter(z,index(z,,1)<>""))(reduce({"Name","Emails","Year","Value"},sequence(counta(A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,c,{a;reduce(makearray(1,4,lambda(r,c,iferror(1/0))),sequence(counta(C1:D1)),lambda(x,y,{x;index(A2:A,c),index(B2:B,c),index(C1:D1,,y),index(C2:D,c,y)}))})))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another shorter approach; assuming your source table is at the top left of a sheet, use the following:

```
={{"Name","Email","Year","Value"};arrayformula(split(flatten(A2:A5&"|"&B2:B5&"|"&C1:D1&"|"&C2:D5),"|"))}
```

Change the cell references to match your real dataset.